# How do I restore a previous catalog after upgrading Lightroom Classic to v13.2?'

Tags: lightroom, backup

Immediately after upgrading Lightroom Classic to v13.2 I accidentally undid all the Flags in all the photos. I want to restore the catalogs from v12 but when I did the update to v13.2 I got a message that said (I think) that the catalog format for v13.2 was incompatible with the catalog format for v12.  How to I revert my Lightroom Classic to v12 so that I can restore the compatible catalog?
(Windows 10)

Comment: Usually on such upgrades LR keep old catalog. Did you try to open v12 catalog and repeat again the conversion process?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to revert the version of Lightroom. When LR updates the catalogue it creates a new copy and leaves the old one in place. You simply need to tell it to open the old catalogue (File>Open Catalog) and it will upgrade it again as a new copy.

After a while it is a good idea to delete old catalogues and backups as they can take up a fair bit of drive space,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Romeo Ninov for pointing me in the right direction. Guidelines for reverting to a previous version of Lightroom are in the Adobe Creative Cloud app for Desktop. The option to install an older version appears when you click on the three dots
[image: CreativeCloud screenshot]

After the older version installed it launched and announced that the current catalog wasn't compatible and asked if I wanted to install from an older catalog - that's exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

That's a better answer than my answer.  I didn't realize that a new version of LightRoom will upgrade catalogs created in older versions. Thanks.

Comment: please do not post a comment as an answer, that goes against the idea how stackexchange works.